# Calling a table inside a function

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have a function (genDist) that returns a table, and another function (VVPPx) that requires that table to calculate other things. When i run the functions separate, they work (first create the table and then select the table for the other function); however if i write the function VVPX(genDist(97),N,0.03) it doesn't work. Am i missing something?

```
Function genDist(intX As Integer) As Variant    
Dim disTable() As Double, foo As Double, limsup As Integer, k As Integer    
limsup = 100 - intX    
ReDim disTable(1 To limsup + 1, 1 To 2)    
disTable(1, 1) = 0: disTable(1, 2) = 0: foo = 1    
For k = 1 To limsup    
foo = foo * (1 - ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(intX - 15 + 2 + k, 2))    
disTable(k + 1, 1) = 1 - foo    
disTable(k + 1, 2) = k    
Next k    
genDist = disTable()    
End Function  

Function VVPPx(DistTable As Range, NoSimu As Long, dblTaux As Double) As Variant    
Dim A() As Double, j As Long    
ReDim A(1 To NoSimu) As Double    
For j = 1 To NoSimu    
    A(j) = 1 / (1 + dblTaux) ^ AgeDeath(DistTable)        
Next j    
VVPPx = A()    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Gendist returns a variant containing an array but VVPPx requires a Range as input.